# C++ Integer Followed by char gets accepted as an input

Tags: c++, validation, cin

I am using a function to check that my input in an integer only:

```
    int input;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cin >> input;
        if (!std::cin)
        {
            std::cout << "Bad Format. Please Insert an integer! " << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }
        else
            return input;
    }
```

However when inputing a integer followed by a char, **eg. 3s**, the integer gets accepted and the message gets printed.

How can I make sure that the input in such format does not get accepted, nor do input in form **4s 5**, so when the integer appears after the space.

Comment: `std::getline` and unsure parsed line is empty afterward?

Comment: char is also an int

Comment: ```std::cin``` into a string and validate the string using regex or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because chars in c++ are represented by their numeric value in the ascii table, you can try regular expressions like this:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
    std::string str;
    std::regex regex_int("-?[0-9]");
    while (true)
    {
        std::cin >> str;
        if (regex_match(str, regex_int))
        {  
           int num = std::stoi(str);
           //do sth
           break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fixed the problem Thank you.

Comment: *"That happens because chars in c++ are represented by their numeric value"* No, here, the issue is that `std::cin >> input;` stops once int has been read (so it remains extra char in `std::cin`).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a regular expression that duplicates the validation that `std::stoi` does. Just use `std::stoi`:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
std::size_t end;
int result = std::stoi(input, &end);
if (end != input.size())
    // error
```